# how can i change the css style on click with table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to set up menu using the css and a table:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>MONITORING</title>

<style type="text/css">
.menutext {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.headtext {
    font::"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #003299;
}
table.menu {
    border: thin solid #000;
    background-color: #003299;
    text-align:center;
    font:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFF;
}
table.menu td:hover {
    background-color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#003299;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%" height="147"><img src="images/logo.png" width="300" height="128" align="left"></td>
    <td width="70%" align="center" valign="middle" class="headtext">MONITORING</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>


<table class="menu" width="100%" height="22" align="center" id="menu">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">MON1</td>
    <td width="25%">MON2</td>
    <td width="25%">MON3</td>
    <td width="25%">MON4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been able to set up td:hover but I would like to be able to keep the hover setting when I have clicked on td. Additionally I would be grateful if you could let me know how to achieve that if mon1 has been chosen if i click mon2 the mon2 will change the css to a table.menu td:hover (or a new one created with the same properties) and mon1 will go back to the original css which is table.menu.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript code? You can't trigger events on CSS, except behavioral animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well add this inside your TDs

```
class="menu-item" onclick="selectMenu($(this))"
```

Then use this javascript code, you must include fist of all jquery.min.js

```
function selectMenu(e){
        $('.menu-item').removeClass('clicked');
        e.addClass('clicked');
}
```

Add this css too

```
.clicked{
        background-color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
        font: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, Serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #003299;
 }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity If I would like to additionally on click open a link in a different frame should I use <a href=“content1.html” target="mainFrame"> </a>? The only problem is that it change the css that I'm using to hyperlink (underscored blue). Is there any way to get use the styles used in the question up (with the same problem what if the css changed to on click one). Thank you very much in advance and sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to include jquery.

Put your HTML code as it is.

Add this javascript code after '<\table>'

```
</table>
<script>
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.menu td'), function(el){
        el.addEventListener('click', function(){
            el.classList.toggle('clicked');
        }, false);
    });
</script>
```

add clicked class after 'table.menu td:hover' on your css code

```
table.menu td:hover, .clicked {
    background-color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#003299;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not bothering, well use this CSS:

```css
.linkClicked {
        color: blue /*or whatever/* 
} 
.linkNormal { 
        color: gray 
}
```

Then add this inside your `a`:

```html
class="linkNomal" href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="add here instead your link" onclick="chargeLink($(this))"`
```

Finally, use this function:

```js
function chargeLink(e) {
    $('.linkNormal').removeClass('linkClicked'); 
    e.addClass('linkClicked'); 
    $('.yourframeclass').attr('src', e.attr('data-href'));
}
```